# I want to remove the button in the salesforce

Tags: button

I want to remove the save&new button and replace with the send a sms and i want to delete the sms name in that section?can somebody tell me the solution behind this?
please find a screenshot attached above.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Over-ride Edit button with a Visualforce page.
And use  so you can have the buttons on top and bottom.

SMS Name appears to be the standard Name field. You can prefer to not show it on the visualforce page and it will have Id of the record on save and view.